# node.js のインストールがうまくできない

Tags: linux, node.js, centos

CentOS で `sudo yum install nodejs -y` を実行したところ、
"問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができます。"
と出てきます。どすればいいのでしょうか？

```
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
依存性の解決をしています
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> パッケージ nodejs.x86_64 1:6.17.1-1.el7 を 更新
--> 依存性の処理をしています: nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7 のパッケージ: 1:npm-3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7.x86_64
---> パッケージ nodejs.x86_64 2:8.17.0-1nodesource を アップデート
--> トランザクションの確認を実行しています。
---> パッケージ npm.x86_64 1:3.10.10-1.6.17.1.1.el7 を 更新
---> パッケージ npm.x86_64 1:8.1.2-1.16.13.2.7.el7 を アップデート
--> 依存性の処理をしています: nodejs = 1:16.13.2-7.el7 のパッケージ: 1:npm-8.1.2-1.16.13.2.7.el7.x86_64
--> 依存性解決を終了しました。
エラー: パッケージ: 1:npm-8.1.2-1.16.13.2.7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
             要求: nodejs = 1:16.13.2-7.el7
            削除中: 1:nodejs-6.17.1-1.el7.x86_64 (@epel)
                nodejs = 1:6.17.1-1.el7
            次のものにより更新された: : 2:nodejs-8.17.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.17.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 1:nodejs-16.13.2-7.el7.x86_64 (epel)
                nodejs = 1:16.13.2-7.el7
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.0.0-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.1.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.1.0-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.1.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.1.1-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.1.2-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.1.2-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.1.3-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.1.3-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.1.4-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.1.4-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.2.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.2.0-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.2.1-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.2.1-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.3.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.3.0-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.4.0-1nodesource.el7.centos.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.4.0-1nodesource.el7.centos
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.5.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.5.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.6.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.6.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.7.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.7.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.8.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.8.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.8.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.8.1-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.9.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.9.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.9.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.9.1-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.9.2-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.9.2-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.9.3-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.9.3-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.9.4-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.9.4-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.10.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.10.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.11.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.11.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.11.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.11.1-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.11.2-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.11.2-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.11.3-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.11.3-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.11.4-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.11.4-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.12.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.12.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.13.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.13.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.14.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.14.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.14.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.14.1-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.15.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.15.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.15.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.15.1-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.16.0-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.16.0-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.16.1-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.16.1-1nodesource
            利用可能: 2:nodejs-8.16.2-1nodesource.x86_64 (nodesource)
                nodejs = 2:8.16.2-1nodesource
 問題を回避するために --skip-broken を用いることができます。
```

---

追記
`yum list nodejs`
の実行結果

```
$ yum list nodejs
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
Determining fastest mirrors
 * base: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
google-chrome                                                               3/3
slack                                                                     81/81
インストール済みパッケージ
nodejs.x86_64                  1:6.17.1-1.el7                         @epel     
利用可能なパッケージ
nodejs.x86_64                  2:8.17.0-1nodesource                   nodesource
```

`yum repolist`の実行結果

```
yum repolist
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * epel: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * extras: ftp.jaist.ac.jp
 * updates: ftp.riken.jp
リポジトリー ID     リポジトリー名                                        状態
base/7/x86_64       CentOS-7 - Base                                       10,072
code                Visual Studio Code                                     1,911
epel/x86_64         Extra Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64        13,728
extras/7/x86_64     CentOS-7 - Extras                                        500
google-chrome       google-chrome                                              3
nodesource/x86_64   Node.js Packages for Enterprise Linux 7 - x86_64         119
slack               slack                                                     81
updates/7/x86_64    CentOS-7 - Updates                                     3,411
virtualbox/7/x86_64 Oracle Linux / RHEL / CentOS-7 / x86_64 - VirtualBox     100
repolist: 29,925
```

https://parashuto.com/rriver/tools/updating-node-js-and-npm
このサイトの書いてある通りに実行してもエラーが発生しました。

```
 npm audit
npm ERR! code ENOLOCK
npm ERR! audit This command requires an existing lockfile.
npm ERR! audit Try creating one first with: npm i --package-lock-only
npm ERR! audit Original error: loadVirtual requires existing shrinkwrap file

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-02-15T04_26_48_418Z-debug.log
```

---

追記
`sudo yum remove nodejs npm`
を実行したところ、

```
読み込んだプラグイン:fastestmirror, langpacks
引数に一致しません: nodejs
引数に一致しません: npm
削除対象とマークされたパッケージはありません。
```

と出てきましたが、
node.jsを入れ直すとなぜか上手く？インストール出来たようです。

Comment: 発生している問題の中でおそらく、お使いのcentos及びマシンに対応するnodejsのパッケージの中で、依存性の解決ができなかったためだと思われます。今回の場合`--skip-broken`はあまり適切ではないように思います。(依存性を解決できていないものを使うことになるため)
本来、依存性のあるものを`exclude`オプションで排除しながらinstallすれば良いのですが、依存性に関する問題は、数日のうちに解決することが多いので少し待ってみるのも一つかもしれません。

Comment: 状況を確認するため、`yum list nodejs` と `yum repolist` の実行結果をそれぞれ質問に貼り付けてみて下さい。 / 恐らく複数の yum リポジトリに nodejs が複数バージョン含まれているためコンフリクトを起こしているのだと思います。

Comment: 既にインストール済みな状態のようなので、より正確には「アップデートができない」ではないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

nodesource のリポジトリを追加した際に恐らく何らかの警告が表示されていたかと思いますが、
既に別のリポジトリ (EPEL) から node.js / npm パッケージがインストールされているのが原因です。

まずは既存のインストール済みパッケージをアンインストールしてください。
(必要に応じてバックアップ等を事前に実施してください)

```
$ sudo yum remove nodejs npm
```

その後、改めて nodejs パッケージをインストールします。

```
$ sudo yum install nodejs
```

場合によっては EPEL リポジトリを一時的に無効にした方がよいかもしれません。

```
$ sudo yum --disablerepo=epel install nodejs
```

Comment: `削除対象とマークされたパッケージはありません。`と出てきましたが、よくわかりませんが、node.jsのバージョンは`v17.5.0`がインストールできました。よくわからないですが、解決したような気がします。ありがとうございました。